# See Python error message on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

My server crashes when deploying to Heroku but works fine locally. I get  HTTP error 500. Heroku does not show me the Python error message and traceback, only a short message:

```
2017-07-20T12:13:44.591351+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info
method=POST
path="/open"
host=vast-sands-94937.herokuapp.com
request_id=ff527e2c-59f4-4e43-919c-e02022bef6b2
fwd="109.252.206.46"
dyno=web.1
connect=1ms
service=3ms
status=500
bytes=412
protocol=https
```

But I want to see the complete traceback. How do I see error output from Heroku?
For example, if I write something like:

```
i = None
i = i +1
```

And run this locally, Python will output to console `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'` 
But when I run this on Heroku, I get none of this information.

I was following Heroku set-up described in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-websockets#using-redis-locally-add-to-env. How do I change set-up they use to output all info.

Comment: You mean the `HTTP` error 500? Can you show your `heroku logs` output?

Comment: Can you link your code?

Comment: @SamChats The code does not matter here. I just what to have an ability to do that kind of debugging in general on Heroku. The code involves a lot of WebSocket stuff and that is why it behaves differently locally and on Heroku

Comment: Had it crashed locally, would it have given the traceback?

Comment: @SamChats see my most recent edit

Comment: I think this might be related to the fact that you're using a `web` dyne in contrast to a `worker` one. `worker` is more suitable for running `.py` scripts.

Comment: Any update on this question?